# Overlaying text over images using PIL

Tags: python, jquery-ui, text, overlay, python-imaging-library

Currently our application is restricted to text, images and audio mime types. I have been given the responsibility of adding a new feature - overlaying text on images (similar to snapchat). The image editing will be done on the server side (my task) and the text would be provided by the client using a jquery. I think that the ImageFont module of Python's Imaging Library (PIL) can be used to do this. So my question - how would I go about implementing this? Will the script be similar to this - http://python-catalin.blogspot.com/2010/06/add-text-on-image-with-pil-module.html ? Currently we are using amazon s3 for our object store. If I write the script in our DB API, Will it be major performance issue (the ultimate goal is to have a separate service for image processing)? I am quite new to Python and PIL so any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: Yes, your script will be similar to that. You've asked several fairly broad questions. What have you tried so far? What stumbling blocks have you reached?

Comment: To be honest - right now I am still in the planning phase. I wrote a script that overlays text on top of images (similar to the one in the link). Do you have any experience implementing something like this?